# Hadoop config error

Tags: hadoop, hosts

I am trying to run **Multi Node Cluster of Hadoop** over a LAN Network.
I am running my master as namenode and datanode both
and another machine as datanode

When I started hadoop from master and did jps on master and slave I got

```
master > NameNode
         DataNode
         SecondaryNameNode
         JobTracker
         TaskTracker
         Jps
```

and on slave

```
slave > DataNode
         TaskTracker
         Jps
```

but after a while I get :(

```
slave > Jps
```

so I checked my log of datanode on slave and I am getting this error

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch: Protocol org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DatanodeProtocol version mismatch. (client = 25, server = 26)
```

Is it because of the different versions of hadoop on master and slave???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the same version across the whole cluster.

Comment: Thnkz a lot for helping

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because of using different protocol on master and slave machine.
In this case, slave will not be able to communicate with master machine.